# Word describing 'not content with small achievement, but working hard to achieve higher level'

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

I am looking for a single English word which describes the mental quality of being not content with small achievement, but working hard to achieve higher level. For example, an artist who is not satisfied with winning a prize or fame, but focusing on his art of work and trying to discover a new way of impression and inspiration in his work.

Comment: A person who has these mental qualities is typically said to be `a person with drive` or alternatively a `person with ambition` or `an ambitious person`. Though they are not directly related to this specific mental quality, it is often implied by the aforementioned adjectives.

Comment: "_Driven and discontent_"

Comment: _Misguided_ could be one :)

Answer (score 2):

*Ambitious, career-minded, hustling, driven, hard-charging.*

Answer (score 0):

Consider **aspiring**:

> having a strong desire for personal achievement

definition via *Merriam-Webster Online*.

Answer (score 0):

Try *avaricious*; it’s usually asociated with a desire that extends beyond simple greed but can be used to describe an extreme greed for success, power, or recognition.

Comment: Avaricious means miserly or stingy and has nothing to do with 'working hard'.

Answer (score 0):

How about persevering, conscientious, perfectionist, driven.

Answer (score -1):

*Hungrier* or *thirstier*

[hunger](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hunger?q=hunger) a strong desire or craving:her hunger for knowledge

[thirst](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/thirst?q=thirst%20for#thirst__15) (usually thirst for/after) *literary* have a strong desire for something